# Nested TabNavigator is not getting rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am using a TabNavigator (child navigator) inside another TabNavigator (parent navigator) inside a StackNavigator (Grandparent navigator).

Here is my code.

```
    const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
      Home: { screen: GParentScene, navigationOptions:{title:'MyChats', header:{visible: false}} },
    });

    const GParentScene = TabNavigator({
      A: { screen: ParentScene1 },
      B: { screen: ParentScene2 },
    });
    const ParentScene1 = TabNavigator ({
      Tab1: {screen: ChildScene1},
      Tab2: {screen: ChildScene2}
    });
```

and similar screens for ParentScene2. Here are my simple child scenes.

```
    class ChildScene1 extends React.Component {
      render(){
        return(
          <View>
             <Text> this is content of Tab1 </Text>
          </View>
        )
      }
    }

    class ChildScene2 extends React.Component {
      render(){
        return(
          <View>
             <Text> this is content of Tab2 </Text>
          </View>
        )
      }
    }
```

Now i made a container

```
    class AppContainer extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <SimpleApp screenProps={this.props}/>
        )
      }
    }
    function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
      return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch)
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state){
      console.log('state tree',state)
      return{
        Count: state.Count,
      }
    }
```

and connected it with my redux store in provider

```
    const App = () => (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer />
      </Provider>
    );


    AppRegistry.registerComponent('reduxnav', () => App);
```

i connected a container with my store and passed action and state of state tree as a property to every stack child. I can even get these property.
but here i am stuck with two problem first when my state is changed then property is changed which i am passing to all stack child but it does not cause my component to rerender and

Initially i can see my child tabs. But content inside it does not gets rendered. As soon as i switch from Tabs1 to Tabs2 all the content gets visible. 
Why is this happening? 
[image: when my app opens i see this screen]

I also found out that this is not happening in ios but only in android platform.

Comment: Are you trying to make the TabNavigator1 navigate to a new TabNavigator2 scene via a Stack Segue/Transition? Or are you trying to get a TabNavigator to sit inside of another TabNavigator?

Comment: The code you gave us: https://jsfiddle.net/unLyuebn/ is creating this output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNtcR.png. Is this the effect you are going for?? Nesting two different TabNavigators into the same view?

Comment: @radiovisual thank you for  your reply. I have one screen in stackNavigator that is a TabNavigator and this tab navigator's first screen has another TabNavigator . The content for the newest Tab is not getting rendered initially but when i make a transition between child tabs then i can see the contents .

Comment: When you say "Tabs1 to Tabs2 all the content gets **visible**", do you mean to say "Tabs1 to Tabs2 all the content gets **invisible**?" because when I run your code, it actually works for me. I mean, I get Two TabNavigators in the SAME view (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNtcR.png)) which is odd to me, but all the content of each Tab renders correctly for me when I press on the Tabs.

Comment: @radiovisual when you start the app and you are in A which has two tabs Tabs 1 and Tab2 . is the content of Tabs1 visible without navigating anywhere initially? if yes then i think i have done something wrong in redux :(

Comment: yes. I am using react native version `0.42.3` if that makes any difference.

Comment: Ohh yes. This was the reason. i tested it same code runs fine in 0.42.3 . well thanks a lot for your help. answer the question instead of comments.  :p

Comment: @VaibhavShukla I am facing same problem, did you got resolution ?

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya i used lazyload property on my parent tab bar which somewhat solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code you provided (on React Native version `0.42.3`) which was only modified to add `ParentScene1`, and and the Text Tags were modified:

```
class ChildScene1 extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
         <Text> this is content of Child Tab1 </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class ChildScene2 extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
         <Text> this is content of Child Tab2 </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class ChildScene3 extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
         <Text> this is content of Child Tab3 </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class ChildScene4 extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
         <Text> this is content of Child Tab4 </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const ParentScene1 = TabNavigator ({
    Tab1: { screen: ChildScene1 },
    Tab2: { screen: ChildScene2 }
});

const ParentScene2 = TabNavigator ({
    Tab1: { screen: ChildScene3 },
    Tab2: { screen: ChildScene4 }
});

const GParentScene = TabNavigator({
  A: { screen: ParentScene1 },
  B: { screen: ParentScene2 },
});



const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: GParentScene, navigationOptions:{ title:'MyChats', header:{ visible:false } } },
});

export default SimpleApp;
```

which renders like this for me in the iOS simulator:

[image]

It works to render the Tabs all in one view, where they are "Stacked" on top of each other, but you will be left with a big problem in that your **Tabs won't behave correctly**. Consider this:

1. You click on Tab1.A, making it active, and then
2. Click on Tab2.A making it active,

Now the Parent Screen is trying to render two different Tabs "active" screens, because each of your TabNavigators has an "active" tab.This will cause unpredictable problems for you in your rendering.

Instead, you might be better off Creating a single view, which has your own custom TabBar at the bottom of the view. Otherwise, you will need to find a way to "deactivate" an "active" tab on the "inactive" TabBar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you try this in android simulator. That would be of great help . I did upgrade my react-native and it worked for me in ios. but in android it still has the same issue ! . i am uploading screenshot for reference

Comment: I had to update my answer with some particular problems I was facing with this setup. Turns out, I didn't get it working 100%, there were still problems. The problems I am having are different from yours though. I can get it to render all the tabs, but not with optimal behaviors. See my edits for an update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still cant render tabs initially when i start the app. I have to explicitly select the Tab1 to get it displayed at starting which is kind of annoying.

Comment: You are not facing my problem because you are using  **ios simulater**   Consider going to **android**  and trying it once . i did it and it works fine in ios.